# How do I specify a Forena PDO data source in settings.php?

Tags: forena

I would like to override my [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) data sources in a local settings file for development. I would also like them in settings.php on production for database independent deployment.

I have checked [the documentation](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/help.data#datasources) but a full example is not provided. Can anyone provide a full example?

Answer (score 2):

A sample of what you are looking for can be found in Forena subfolder `repos/sample/settings.php`, it looks like so (and is for 7.x-4.x):

```
<?php
/*
 * Sample Repository configuration file
 */

/*
 * Security provider:  Specify the class name that is used to provide security
 */
$conf['access callback'] = 'user_access';

/*
 * Data provider:
 * Specify the class name that will be used to interpret data block files.
 * Note that data blocks in a repository
 *
 */
$conf['data provider'] = 'FrxPDO';

/*
 * URI:
 * The format of the uri depends on the type of data engine that's being used.
 * In database engines it might be the connection string to the db.  In the file
 * engine it would be the path to the directory containting the files
 */
$local_path = realpath(dirname(drupal_get_path('module','forena').'/forena.info'));
$conf['uri'] = 'sqlite:'. $local_path . '/repos/sample/sample.db';
$conf['debug'] = FALSE;
/**
 * Uncomment the following line to specify a particular path in which to save reports.
 * The default value would be controlled by Forena configuration page. If you'd like users
 * to be able to define their own reports in this repository then you need to make sure that this
 * is writable by the web user (e.g. apache).
 */
// $conf['report_path'] = 'sites/files/reports'
```

Disclosure: I'm a Forena co-maintainer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't accept your answer because I was looking for a way to handle multiple repositories. The version I provided below works to some extent but recently caused problems when migrating reports from one Drupal install to another. Maybe because I am missing both access_callback and user_callback?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a format that works in settings.php. It is actually shown in snippet form in the linked documentation but not fully expanded on.

```
global $_forena_repositories;
$_forena_repositories['source1'] =
  [
    'path' => 'sites/all/forena_repos/source1',
    'title' => 'Source1',
    'data provider' => 'FrxPDO',
    'uri' => 'mysql:host=mydb.site.localhost;dbname=source1;charset=UTF8',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'changeme',
  ];
$_forena_repositories['source2'] =
  [
    'path' => 'sites/all/forena_repos/source2',
    'title' => 'Source2',
    'data provider' => 'FrxPDO',
    'uri' => 'mysql:host=mydb.site.localhost;dbname=source2;charset=UTF8',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'changeme',
  ];
```